# Symfony Locale Modify based on Sub domain

Tags: symfony, routes, sylius

I have a need to set the locale based on subdomain , using Sylius based on Symfony.

I have done the below to make it work, but we need the Locale Code in subdomain mapped to a localcode ( "jp.portal.com" => Locale "ja")

```
#Routing YML 
portal:
    resource : "../../src/proj/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    host: "{_locale}.%site_host%"
    prefix: /
    requirements:
       _locale: 'en|jp'
    defaults: 
     _locale: 'en'
```

Difficulty i have is mapped a non locale code like  'jp' to 'ja'

I have tried with below locale Listiner , but it does not help
I get errors

```
       if (strpos($host, 'jp') !== false) {
            $locale = 'ja';
        }  else {
            $locale = 'en';
        }

        $request->setLocale($locale);
        if (null !== $this->router) {
            $this->router->getContext()->setParameter('_locale', $request->getLocale());
        }
```

I get errors in generate url path througth the site

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template 
("Parameter "_locale" for route "sylius_shop_homepage" must match "jp"
 ("en" given) to generate a corresponding URL.").
```

Comment: I started working on an answer but it will take a while to describe it in detail, so I figured I just give some initial pointers instead. I think part of your problem is conflating country code (jp) with locale (en or ja). You might want to create a mapping from country code to accepted languages in your config. In your listener check for the country code in the url and store it as attribute and (either in the same listener or another one) select the appropriate locale based on the attribute and additional locale-related information, e.g. based on the accept-language settings from the browser.

Comment: In any case you have to be mindful of the priority of your listener as it might interfere with other ones, both from Symfony as well as Sylius. There is a `debug:events` command available that should help identify a fitting priority.